# Download Sentinel images from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, sentinel-2

I am interested in finding a way to download Sentinel images within ArcGIS Pro. As a plugin a script or a Toolbox. I know there are already some solutions like Sentinel Hub etc. However, I am looking for something that doesn't require paying extra for just downloading images. What I would like to be able to do is to download 5 images every 10 days  of a specific area (5 images cover that area). After that, all other processing will be done by ArcMap Pro. I need a tool that I can use it inside ArcGIS Pro like a plugin script or a Toolbox. I am trying to automate that procedure.

Comment: Where are you obtaining the images? Pro doesn't include Sentinel data, or, for the most part, raster download. It does include Python, which means that much is possible, but only to the limits of licensing.

Comment: Obtaining from Copernicus Open Access Hub. (Pro doesn't include Sentinel data) Of course not. I am looking for a script or an API or a plugin or something similar.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify you are looking for an Add-In or Toolbox to access your source, though once it's clear that's what you want, this may be closed as an *opinion-based* list compilation question.

Answer (score 6):

You can access Sentinel 2 in ArcGIS Pro by simply accessing it via the image service provided through the Living Atlas portal built into ArcGIS Pro.

[image: Living Atlas]

By using the info tool you can identify the tile which you can then feed into a definition query:

[image: Identifying tile]

Setting a definition query to filter on tile and date.

[image: Def query]

No tools or scripting required, all accessible via the standard ArcGIS Pro interface.

Comment: What I want exactly. 5 images of a specific area (sxe, swe, sve, swd, svd) every ten days. We want to keep those images for three years and not only RGB Bands.

Comment: You don't actually state in your question that you want multi-spectral images, you simply say "Sentinel", so suggest you update your question.  If you want those then you will need to access sentinel hub for that. 3 second of effort of Googling finds [this](https://www.gis-blog.com/download-sentinel-2-data-using-python-or-command-line/).